# WKHTTPCookieStore.setCookie completion handler not called

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, webkit, wkwebview

I need to share cookies between WKWebView instances - for this i'm using a single WKWebViewConfiguration instance which is then used to init every WKWebView.

In order to do this I assume I have to use a shared WKProcessPool, ex:

```
let websiteDataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.default()
websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.add(self)

let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
configuration.websiteDataStore = websiteDataStore
configuration.processPool = WKProcessPool()   /* !!! */
```

However doing so causes the setCookie completion handler to NOT fire.

```
let cookieStore = self.webConfiguration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore
     cookieStore.setCookie(cookie, completionHandler: {
})
```

If i do not set the WKProcessPool (*) instance - then completion block fires fine, but obviously WebViews do not see the cookies ; /  Did anyone encounter this? Ideas on how else to share the cookies?

iOS: 11.2.6

Comment: Another interesting observation is that this problem does not occur on simulator.

Comment: This problem does not occur on iOS 12, but another cookie problem occurs on iOS 12. I hate WKWebView.

Comment: This callback is not triggered if the method is inside of DispatchQueue.main.async / sync.

Answer (score 5):

After further testing I've managed to find solution - although i'm not sure what is happening. In short - above **completion handler fires OK after WKWebView is instantiated.**

In my case I need to set some cookies after login (so no webviews are displayed ATM). So calling setCookie only queues these operations somewhere - they are flushed when web client is fired. If someone can link documentation - that's be great!

---

### UPDATE

So as this issue is still present - I've finally got back to this. My solution for now is to:

1. Cache cookie value in keychain (every time app calls HTTPCookieStore.setCookie   - which may complete or not (which is the problem)
2. When HTTPCookieStore.setCookie{ }  completion block fires (confirmation that cookie was indeed set) i then remove the value from keychain and webview is now responsible for lifecycle of the cookie value)
3. On every start of app i check if cookie values are cached in keychain -> if so HTTPCookieStore.setCookie()

Above can loop infinitely UNTIL webview is actually opened.

Comment: hey, i have a similar problem, but it's not around the processpool - i don't believe you have to create a new one for cookies to work (i didn't have to)

but, only on device, if i click into my webview the first time, my completion handler returns, and then x out and click back in, it returns, and then x out and click back in a 3rd or 4th or 5th time, at some point it stops returning and never returns again.


I tried to instantiate the wkwebview before the calls to set cookie, and tried setting the processpool at various points, but nothing has worked thus far :(

Comment: Hey @BinyaKoatz I am facing a similar issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Any updates here? I'm facing the same problem. Even with the wkwebview instantiated before.

Comment: Yup agreed. I get the same problem here. Any updates or radar's filed?

Comment: Hey @user3911483 and Vall0n and Rafthecalf - filed a radar, it's marked as a "DUPLICATE OF 38857415", and OPEN, so they know that it's happening but haven't fixed it yet.

The project I was working on got cancelled, so I've stopped pursuing solutions to this bug, but I'll keep y'all updated on the radar! Sorry for the long radio silence!

Answer (score 1):

My problem was with deleting cookies to log a user out of the application. The completion handler for `getAllCookies()` was not firing, so what is working for me is forcing the `webView` to reload which will flush the queue and delete the cookies.

```
webView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.getAllCookies { cookies in
    for cookie in cookies {
        if cookie.name == "authentication" {
            self.webView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.delete(cookie)
        }
    }
}
webView.reload()
```

Comment: reload webview never flush cookies... how you can say this ?